# How do I model a 'has a' database relationship with multiple principles?

Tags: database, entity-framework, database-design, entity-framework-core

In code I have an object graph that looks like this:

```c#
public class Author
{
   public int AuthorId { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Publisher
{
   public int PublisherId { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
   public int AddressId { get; set; }
   public string Postcode { get; set; }
}
```

How do I model this in a relational database schema?

This needs to be a 0-1..1 relation, i.e. Authors and Publishers may either have or not have an Address.

Ideally Addresses would have to be referenced by either an Author or a Publisher but not both.

Massive bonus respect if you can model it in Entity Framework Core using navigation properties and have cascade delete remove the Address when an Author or Publisher is removed. (But I'm betting no one will be able to).

I'd list all the things I've tried, but the post would be so long no one would read it. It'll be quicker just to say I've tried everything I can think of.

Comment: Can we add properties to `Address` class or it should stay the way it is now?

Comment: You may add properties to Address. All tables may be adjusted as required to establish the desired relation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways you can achieve the goal in EF Core. The key point is that `Address` will be the *dependent* end of the relationships and it will contain *optional* FKs to the *principal* entities `Author` and `Publisher`.

Here are the possible `Address` models and configurations:

**(1) `Address` with explicit FK and navigation properties**

*Model:*

```
public class Address
{
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public string Postcode { get; set; }

    public int? AuthorId { get; set; }
    public Author Author { get; set; }

    public int? PublisherId { get; set; }
    public Publisher Publisher { get; set; }
}
```

*Configuration:*

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Author>()
    .HasOne(e => e.Address)
    .WithOne(e => e.Author)
    .HasForeignKey<Address>(e => e.AuthorId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

modelBuilder.Entity<Publisher>()
    .HasOne(e => e.Address)
    .WithOne(e => e.Publisher)
    .HasForeignKey<Address>(e => e.PublisherId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

**(2) `Address` with navigation properties only**

*Model:*

```
public class Address
{
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public string Postcode { get; set; }

    public Author Author { get; set; }

    public Publisher Publisher { get; set; }
}
```

*Configuration:*

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Author>()
    .HasOne(e => e.Address)
    .WithOne(e => e.Author)
    .HasForeignKey<Address>("AuthorId")
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

modelBuilder.Entity<Publisher>()
    .HasOne(e => e.Address)
    .WithOne(e => e.Publisher)
    .HasForeignKey<Address>("PublisherId")
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

**(3) `Address` with explicit FK properties only**

*Model:*

```
public class Address
{
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public string Postcode { get; set; }

    public int? AuthorId { get; set; }

    public int? PublisherId { get; set; }
}
```

*Configuration:*

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Author>()
    .HasOne(e => e.Address)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey<Address>(e => e.AuthorId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

modelBuilder.Entity<Publisher>()
    .HasOne(e => e.Address)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey<Address>(e => e.PublisherId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

**(4) `Address` without explicit FK and navigation properties**

*Model:*

```
public class Address
{
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
}
```

*Configuration:*

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Author>()
    .HasOne(e => e.Address)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey<Address>("AuthorId")
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

modelBuilder.Entity<Publisher>()
    .HasOne(e => e.Address)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey<Address>("PublisherId")
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

**Reference: [Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships)**

Comment: I think also Owned Types will be an option, don't you? ("All tables may be adjusted as required to establish the desired relation").

Comment: @Gert Sure. But the way I understand it, OP explicitly wants 1 to 0..1 relationship (*Authors and Publishers may either have or not have an Address*) while owned types represent 1 to 1 (i.e. required) relationship like EF6 complex types?

Comment: Yes, it's the ef-core equivalent of complex types. But of course it's not optional, so I guess it doesn't exactly fit the bill. It may be worth considering though for OP, because it greatly simplifies the data model, the address fields being part of the owner table. Drawback: you always have to create *two* entities (`Publisher` and `Address` etc) if you want to create *one*. But a little factory method will hide that inconvenience. I think I would go for it (but I'm a teeny weeny allergic to polymorphic associations and nullable foreign keys).

Comment: This answer has been extremely helpful. Many thanks.